# Query documents in one collection that aren't referenced in another collection with Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a firestore DB where I'm storing polls in one collection and responses to polls in another collection. I want to get a document from the poll collection that isn't referenced in the responses collection for a particular user.

The naive approach would be to get all of the poll documents and all of the responses filtered by user ID then filter the polls on the client side. The problem is that there may be quite a few polls and responses so those queries would have to pull down a lot of data.

So my question is, is there a way to structure my data so that I can query for polls that haven't been completed by a user without having to pull down the collections in their entirety? Or more generally, is there some pattern to use when you need to query for documents in one collection that aren't referenced by another?

The documents in each of the collections look something like this:

Polls:

```
{
    question: string;
    answers: Answer[];
}
```

Responses:

```
{
    userId: string;
    pollId: string;
    answerId: string;
}
```

Anyhelp would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Queries in Firestore can only return documents from one collection (or from all collections with the same name) and can only contain conditions on the data that they actually return.

Since there's no way to filter based on a condition in some other documents, you'll need to include the information that you want to filter on in the `polls` documents.

For example, you could include a `completionCount` field in each poll document, that you initially set to 0, and then update only every poll completion. With that in place, the query becomes a simple query on the `completionCount` field of the `polls` collection.

---

For a specific user I'd actually add all polls to their profile document, and remove them from there. Duplicating data is usually the easiest (and sometimes only) way to implement use-cases such as this.

---

If you're worried about having to add each new poll to each new user profile when it is created, you can also query all polls on their creation timestamp when you next load a user profile and perform that sync at that moment.

1. load user profile,
2. check when they were last active,
3. query for new polls,
4. add them to user profile.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think adding completionCount to polls would help. That would only tell me that not all users have completed a poll. Not that a particular user hasn't completed it. It seems like if the data I want to filter by needs to be on the polls documents then I'd have to have every user who hasn't completed the poll listed on each poll and remove them from that list when they complete it. But that would quickly make the polls documents larger than allowed by firebase if I had just a few thousand users.

Comment: For a specific user I'd actually add all polls to their profile document, and remove them from there. Duplicating data is usually the easiest (and sometimes only) way to implement use-cases such as this. --- If you're worried about having to add each new poll to each new user profile when it is created, you can also query all polls on their creation timestamp when you next load a user profile and perform that sync at that moment. 1) load user profile, 2) check when they were last active, 3) query for new polls, 4) add them to user profile/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That sounds like something I could do. If I give each poll an int ID then store them all for each user in array on their profile, that should give me a lot of room for a large number of polls without getting close to the document size limit. 

If you post this as the answer then I'd mark it as accepted for sure :)